# Appium - Defining Elements hidden behind hamburger menu

Tags: python, selenium, appium, hamburger-menu

I'm having a problem defining elements on a mobile site currently using Appium and Python. I have a hamburger menu on the site and, when this is clicked on, a number of links are shown.

I have tried defining these 'hidden' elements using MobileBy and ExpectedConditions (see below). When I do this however I get an error stating that the object doesn't exist as I haven't expanded the hamburger menu yet.

ExpectedCondition version:

```
self.aboutLink = WebDriverWait(self.driver.instance, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((
            MobileBy.LINK_TEXT, "About")))
```

MobileBy version

```
self.driver.instance.find_element(MobileBy.LINK_TEXT, "About").click()
```

When it comes to the test itself, it fails as the aboutLink object was defined above and cannot be seen until the hamburger menu is clicked.

```
 @allure.step("Validate homepage links")
 def validate_links(self):

    self.hamburgerLink.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    # self.about.click()
    self.aboutLink.click()
```

Do you guys know of any good way around this? I want to create reusable objects and not have to depend on clicking the hamburger menu beforehand to be able to define these objects (like the links hidden in the menu).

Thanks

Comment: Can you able to locate that hidden link by manually inspecting?

Comment: @AliCSE Yeah, if I first open the hamburger link and then click on the About link it finds the element fine.

Comment: Ok... There is no other option then, you have to click on the hamburger menu link first..

Comment: @AliCSE Thanks for the reply. So there is no way to define an element in Python that isn't currently present without Python throwing an error?

Comment: Yes... as it is not visible until you click on that link, you may not able to detect it. May be try with JavaScriptExecutor once, it may work...

Comment: EC.visibility_of_element_located waits for element to be visible ;) Try presence_of_element_located.

Comment: @Angusiasty I've tried this too and it doesn't work either - something which I found unusual as the object is technically 'present' behind the hamburger menu...